# No module named 'pmdarima'

Tags: python, import, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, pmdarima

Im using the jupyter notebook from remote access and want to import the pmdarima for the auto_arima to select the arima model. How can I install the pmdarima through remote access ?

import auto_arima package

```
from pmdarima import auto_arima
```

The result:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pmdarima'
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you can do `!pip install pmdarima` in a jupyter cell and it should install the package in where ever the jupyter server is running and the python installed in it.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you are using `Conda`, access the prompt for the environment that you are working with and install the module `pmdarima` by running

```
conda install -c saravji pmdarima
```

([Source](https://anaconda.org/Saravji/pmdarima))

---

Alternatively one might use pip ([pmdarima pypi](https://pypi.org/project/pmdarima/))

```
pip install pmdarima
```

Answer (score 1):

Open up the Anaconda Command prompt and run **pip3 install pmdarima**

Worked like a charm for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

First of all check your internet connection. Then try the following in your jupyter:

```
pip install pmdarima
```

Then reboot.

Answer (score 0):

## in Jupyternotebook

!pip install pmdarima

## for conda environments

conda install -c saravji pmdarima

## from command line in windows

pip install pmdarima

Comment: Keshav, you no longer want to suggest using en exclamation point in combination with `pip` for working in notebooks. The modern magics `%pip install` and `%conda install` were added that overcome the environment issues that can arise when using an exclamation point with `pip`. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about the recently added magic commands.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have another conda environment where jupyter notebook is running? If so, you can switch to that conda environment using "conda activate {your jupyter notebook env}" before installing new packages.